# How to find the centroid of different sections of an image?

Tags: image, matlab, centroid

I have an image that I want to divide in three parts and find the centroid of the parts separately and display them on original image, I used blkproc for dividing the image in [1 3] grids, but can't display the centroids. Here is the code I wrote,

```
i=imread('F:\line3.jpg');

i2=rgb2gray(i);

bw=im2bw(i2);

imshow(bw)

fun=@(x) regionprops(x,'centroid');

b=blkproc(bw,[1 3],fun);
```

But I can't get to display the centroids, as well as get their values. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the plot command to plot over the top of the image. 
Whatever you [X,Y] centroid coordinates are, say cx(1:3) and cy(1:3)
numCentroids is the number of centroids you are plotting.

---

```
hold on;
for ii = 1:length(numCentroids)
    plot(cx(ii),cy(ii),'Marker','s','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerEdgeColor','k')
end
```

If you wanted to write more elegant code, you could run the plot command once across all your centroids and then make the line style type invisible. The answer I supplied should work though.

Here's an example image with made up centroids.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strong recommendation - use blockproc instead of blkproc. It is better designed and easier to use.

Now, first of all, the second input to blockproc is the blocksize and not the grid size. So if you want to divide your image into [1 3] grid, which I understand as a single row of three blocks, then you should set your blocksize as:

```
 blocksize = [size(i,1) ceil(size(i,2)/3)];
```

The second thing is to turn off the 'TrimBorder' parameter in blockproc. The code would look something like:

```
 fun=@(x) regionprops(x,'centroid');
 blocksize = [size(i,1) ceil(size(i,2)/3)];
 b=blockproc(bw,blocksize,fun,'TrimBorder',false);
```

One minor thing - I would recommend not using the variable name 'i'. By default it represents the imaginary number i = sqrt(-1); in Matlab.